# Browser does not load certain pages

Tags: firefox, chromium, browser

I installed UBUNTU 12.04 and configured for internet access. No issues there. However, my browser (firefox, chromium) is not able to load/display certain pages (mail.yahoo.com, thehindu.com, in.yahoo.com) after loading the web page title. The browser does not have problem with other sites (google, msn, ubuntu, etc...). Any reason why only certain pages are not loading?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a bad DNS (Domain Name Service). It's used to look up the numbers that your computer needs to connect to websites.

Go to your network settings. Edit the connection you use for Internet. Under "IPv4 Settings" tab, change the "Method:" scroll down to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only". Then in the box labeled "DNS servers:" put in `8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`

This will set your computer to use Google's public DNS which is a fast and reliable DNS.